# Does request() helper work with laravel queue

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, queue, helper

I am trying to send email using laravel queue and database jobs table. In one of my file which is generating pdf which is attached with email has helper request()->organization, however it is throwing some sort of exception does laravel queue supports request() helper with queue?

Error:

```
#0 /var/www/app/Http/Services/Payslip.php(18): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'Trying to get p...', '/var/www/app/Ht...', 18, Array)
```

Answer (score 0):

Send the request data in the __construct function